# What is the difference between "state-transition-matrix" and a transition matrix?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, control-theory, linear-control

What's the difference between a state-transition-matrix and a transition matrix (say, for an ergodic Markov Chain) that is typically taught in a basic probability theory course?  This is the first time I have heard of a state-transition-matrix.

Wikipedia does not offer much reading material on it.

I found some online notes from a university but, weirdly, what I am reading is a bunch of differential equations.

Are the entries of the state-transition-matrix analogous to the transition probabilities of a transition matrix (of some Markov chain)?

Thanks,

Comment: what makes you think they are two different things ?

Comment: Hi @user1952009, because in one example that I found online...the entry of the state-transition-matrix is *negative*, which means it can't be a probability...

Comment: Unless I am reading bad notes online... @user1952009

Comment: ok I think I understood : the [state transition matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_matrix) is a matrix for obtaining the state $S_{t+1}$ from the previous state $S_t$ : depending on the dynamic system, it can be any matrix. while a Markov chain transition matrix is a special case of state transition matrix : the matrix for obtaining the probability distribution for $X_{t+1}$ knowing the probability distribution for $X_t$. (it has the constraint that $p_t(i) \ge 0$ and $\sum_i p_t(i) = 1 \implies $ with $p_{t+1} = M p_t$ : $p_{t+1}(i) \ge 0$ and $\sum_i p_{t+1}(i) = 1$)

Comment: ahh...interesting!  so, if my state-transition-matrix were describing, say, a biological system, then to update the state of the system I would just need to multiply the state-transition-matrix with the current state vector -- **just like** how it's done for Markov chain transition matrices.  Do you agree,  @user1952009?  Or, is the matrix-multiplication to update the probability vector...*specific* to the study of Markov chain / Stochastic matrices?

Comment: once I understand the very basics, @user1952009, the next hurdle is to understand how to compute one of these matrices...so far, I see a bunch of differential equations from various online sources...which was not what I expected to find.  I had expected to find a bunch of probability-type of notes instead.

Comment: yes because on wikipedia they consider only continuous time dynamical systems defined by some differential equations, transforming those into state transition matrices (depending on time, for obtaining $S_t$ from $S_0$) can be quite complicated. do you really need understanding those ? stay in the Markov chain world.